# Using EPPlus 6.1.3, how do I assign a chart series to a secondary Y axis?

Tags: epplus, yaxis

I have a chart with two line graph series. They plot ok but I want to show one of them on a secondary Y axis.

Here is my code (in VB.Net but C# responses are fine):

```
Dim destinationChart As ExcelChart = newWorksheet.Drawings.AddChart("AdStats", sourceChart.ChartType)
destinationChart.SetPosition(18, 0, 3, 0)
destinationChart.SetSize(800, 500)

Dim Views As ExcelChartSerie = destinationChart.Series.Add("B18:B31", "A18:A31")
Views.Header = newWorksheet.Cells(17, 2).Value

Dim Inquiries As ExcelChartSerie = destinationChart.Series.Add("C18:C31", "A18:A31")
Inquiries.Header = newWorksheet.Cells(17, 3).Value
```

I want to plot the Views series on the secondary Y axis. I have not tried to establish and assign the secondary axis because I can't find any properties that apply to that step.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.

```
Dim destinationChart As ExcelChart = newWorksheet.Drawings.AddChart("AdStats", sourceChart.ChartType)
destinationChart.SetPosition(18, 0, 3, 0)
destinationChart.SetSize(800, 500)
                            
destinationChart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add(eChartType.LineMarkers)

Dim Views As ExcelChartSerie = destinationChart.Series.Add("B18:B31", "A18:A31")
Views.Header = newWorksheet.Cells(17, 2).Value

Dim Inquiries As ExcelChartSerie = 
destinationChart.Series.Add("C18:C31", "A18:A31")
Inquiries.Header = newWorksheet.Cells(17, 3).Value

destinationChart.UseSecondaryAxis = True
```

The solution is to add the 4th line and the last line:
destinationChart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add(eChartType.LineMarkers)
and
destinationChart.UseSecondaryAxis = True